# C++ Accessing IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 without opening file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

As the question says, is it a possibility to read IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 without actually opening and reading the entire PE file ?

Using ZwQuerySystemInformation to get system modules, and then casting RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION I can access the following:

```
typedef struct _RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION {
        HANDLE Section;
        PVOID MappedBase;
        PVOID ImageBase;
        ULONG ImageSize;
        ULONG Flags;
        USHORT LoadOrderIndex;
        USHORT InitOrderIndex;
        USHORT LoadCount;
        USHORT OffsetToFileName;
        UCHAR  FullPathName[256];
    } RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION, *PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION;
```

But I also want to access IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 without opening and reading the PE file.

Is that even possible ? If so, can someone provide me an example ? I would really appreciate it!

**Update:**

Really upset about the fact that my question was "unclear", which also stopped me from asking anything else on stackoverflow. So I will now now try to explain better what I want to do.

I wan to access OptionalHeader.ImageBase for any module loaded in the system.

Currently opening and reading the PE file which is not loaded into the system, I can access this information:

```
// definitons

union {
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER idh;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 inth32;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 inth64;
};

LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset = {};

// code to open file

NtReadFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, &inth64, sizeof(inth64), &ByteOffset, 0);

// More code
```

And I can now read &inth64.OptionalHeader.ImageBase.

However, when the module is loaded into the system I cannot perform the same action (open file, read file) due to privileges amongst others.

So I enumerate the loaded modules using ZwQuerySystemInformation, but I cannot access here IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64, instead I can only access RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION which does contain *ImageBase* but it's not the same as *OptionalHeader.ImageBase* for some reason. ( is it because one is PVOID and one ULONGLONG ? )

I think you should be more than able to understand what I want to achieve.

Comment: How are you going to read it without first opening the file? If you don't want to read the entire file, don't. Just read the part you need. Or are you actually asking about getting information for modules loaded into your process?

Comment: Yes and no, maybe I was not explicit enough. I am listing modules inside the system, not my process. And I want to access IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 inside any ( or all ) modules in the system, but at this point I can only do it by opening the file, reading it entiry... and accesing IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64. So that is my question, how can I access IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64  without reading the entire file, because doing this often and depending on the file count and size it can be very bad...

Comment: Why would you read the entire file? Seek to the start of the optional header and read it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sound easy and good, but how ? There is no such examples out there, these are undocumented functions... and from my "test" I only crashed everything.

Comment: At the moment you say that you read the entire file, and then you pick out the optional header. So don't do that. Read just the part of the file that contains the optional header. If you already know how to pick it out of the entire file as a byte array, you already know how to seek within the file to the start of the optional header.

Comment: Ah I understand what you say now, but I would like to avoid reading the file in the first place ? This is my point, don't open, don't read... just access the struct, is that possible ?

Comment: Well, `ZwQuerySystemInformation` with `RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION` is undocumented anyway, and who knows whether it is available on all versions of Windows, for instance future ones not yet released.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, but do you understand what I am trying to do now ?

Comment: Are you asking about what appears to be premature optimization? Or are you afraid of the tedious work to continuously open and read from files? Have you considered file mapping objects? That allows you to access PE entries as if they were memory, and prevent to read more file data than you actually need (rounded to the page granularity).

Comment: @IInspectable "are you afraid of the tedious work to continuously open and read from files?" - this is exactly what I am afraid of, because I will do this very often, and I need another solution that can work fast without causing problems.

Comment: So *"tedious"* isn't the issue, but *"performance"* is? Have you profiled? If you have, and it turns out to be too slow, have you tried using file mapping objects instead? Have you profiled?

Comment: Yes I did several tests, and it's very painful to go through the process of Open,Read,Read again just to get to that structure... and no I have not tried file mapping yet, because I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

`PVOID ImageBase;` will show you virtual address of executable file. When you try to read headers from that address using [`ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ImageBase, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) there may be issue:  due to reading from *virtual* memory address, Windows may actually reads information from disk (swap file).

Comment: Well thanks for the answer... but my question is about "not reading" anything, or opening anything...

Comment: No I don't, and this is what I am trying to avoid in the first place... maybe you did not understand my question, maybe I did not explain properly.

Comment: @Norbert It almost seems like you want the information to materialise out of thin air.

Comment: @NorbertBoros, I catched your question now, and then see no answer to "do not open anything" because there is no way to obtain informations from something without gaining read access to it.

Comment: great, so if you look at this article: http://blog.csdn.net/qq125096885/article/details/52875797 I would like to access OPTIONAL HEADERS in the for loop. Is that possible ? without open/read... again.

Comment: @NorbertBoros, maybe you want not entire `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64` structure, but specific fields?

Comment: Yep, I would be happy getting AddressOfEntryPoint :)

Comment: @NorbertBoros neither structures returned by `ZwQuerySystemInformation()` (even RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION_EX), nor kernel structures contain `AddressOfEntryPoint` since it used only at startup. You **must** open handle to file or to process with this library loaded. Another way to read library header - load it with `LoadLibraryEx(.., LOAD_AS_DATAFILE, ...)`.

Comment: So it is impossible then.... back to square one.